# Phantomjs + Google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS on my webpage. Right now, I'm just testing things (like screenshots, clicks, custom resolutions, custom ip... etc) and I'm trying to add to my website to Google Analytics.

In the PhantomJS script, I'm using a function to change proxy automatically with a text file with some private proxies I have got. Changkng the IP works perfectly - confirmed through screenshots - but in Analytics I'm not receiving any visits.

Can someone help me and give some tips to send visits with PhantomJS to google analytics?

Thanks in advance!

Edited:
I added the default google analytics script they give to me,in the head of my webpage.
And this is the PhantomJS code:

```
var system = require("system");
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.customHeaders = {
"Referer": "http://www.google.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36",
"Connection": 'keep-alive',
"Accept": 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,* /*;q=0.8',
"Accept-Enconding": 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
"Accept-Language": 'en;q=0.8',
"Request-protocol": 'HTTP/1.1',
"Request-URI": '/'
};
page.settings.loadImages = false;
page.open("http://exampleurl.com/", function (status) {
    page.render('test.png');
    console.log('Done!');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Can you post details on how you included the GA tracking code, which tracking code you are using, and also how you are sending hits? Also, you can use a tool like GA Debugger to see if you are sending hits successfully. Data in GA doesn't show up immediately in your reports until it has been processed, which may take up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set "page.settings.loadImages" to true, as GA is using gif pixel to collect data.